# iOS - Place an image / container view above navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For some design purpose, I need to place an image above the navigation bar.

Apple is pretty strict on not changing Nav Bar Height.. and I won't go there.

It's kind of a big app, so I won't have to change each controller apart.

My controllers are mostly presented in nav controllers, so I thought making an extension of UINavigationController will do the trick (so far it does). Anyone have ideas about this ?

```
extension UINavigationController {

override open func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        // This add space under my nav bar
        self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 80, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        
        // Need to find a way to move down my nav and add the logo above
    }
}
```

}

[image: Here a visual of what it is expecting]

Comment: You might go with a transparent nav bar of normal height and then just let the view go full-screen underneath it.  You could just put an opaque view where you have "nav bar" above and then the actual nav bar contents would look normal (although they might overlap logo container in that case).  Still might look a little funky though to a typical iOS user so wouldn't be shocked at push back during review

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to place an image is in the Navigation title:

```swift
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

If you want something more customizable, I would suggest you create a View with a 0 constraint with SafeArea.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but if you add a view in your nav bar, it will works, but you will be constraint with a maximum height of 44px, since you can't change the nav bar height.

Answer (score 0):

Add this views in your xib:

[image]

And create your navigationController in your class, like this:

```
import UIKit

class TopLogoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        controller.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .green
        controller.navigationBar.barTintColor = .green
        controller.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        controller.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        addChild(controller)
        containerView.addSubview(controller.view)

        controller.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        controller.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```